# using getobject() threw MissingManifestResourceException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, resources, resourcemanager

I use Resources to store different string for localization purposes in my MVC application.
I am using an HttpHandler to process JavaScript and change the `Translate(KEY)` calls to the actual localized string value from the resource.
This comes for here: [Localize text in JavaScript files in ASP.NET](http://madskristensen.net/post/Localize-text-in-JavaScript-files-in-ASPNET.aspx)

The problem is when i call the getObject Method from my Resource manager I get `MissingManifestResourceException Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.`

here Is the relevant code portion (The error comes from line 6 in the snippet below):

```
private string TranslateScript(string text)
{
    MatchCollection matches = REGEX.Matches(text);
    ResourceManager manager = new ResourceManager(typeof(CamelotShiftManagement.Strings.SharedStrings));

    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
        object obj = manager.GetObject(match.Groups[1].Value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); //This throws the MissingManifestResourceException for some reson!!!!
        if (obj != null)
        {
            text = text.Replace(match.Value, CleanText(obj.ToString()));
        }
    }

    return text;
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem but I can't explain why is that happening. (yet)

I found this post [Problems with ResourceManager and neutral culture in Asp.Net MVC](http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/problems-with-resourcemanager-and-neutral-culture-in-asp-net-mvc/)
and followde the steps he did.
I have chage the line:

```
ResourceManager manager = new ResourceManager(typeof(CamelotShiftManagement.Strings.SharedStrings));
```

To:

```
ResourceManager manager = CamelotShiftManagement.Strings.SharedStrings.ResourceManager;
```

Basically it seems as thou each resource file has a static referance to a ResourceManager that handles this resource file.

That solved my problem.
Having said that, I am still unsure as to why the method I used before did not work...